# VB.NET Json Parse

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing

I'm trying to process the JSON input below.  The code (bottom) throws

```
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. 
Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. 
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Input:

```
[
{
"data": [
    {
    "photos": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "test Post",
                "images": [
                {
                    "height": 1024,
                    "source": "https://127.0.0.1:8080/image1.png",
                    "width": 1204
                },
                {
                    "height": 1204,
                    "source": "https://127.0.0.1:8080/image2.png",
                    "width": 1204
                }
                ],
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(result.ToString)
Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

Dim jsonString As String = Nothing
Dim index As Integer = 0
For Each item As JProperty In data
    item.CreateReader()
    Select Case item.Name
        Case "data"
            jsonString = item.Value.ToString
    End Select
Next

ser = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
data = ser.Children().ToList
For Each item As JProperty In data
    item.CreateReader()
    Select Case item.Name
        Case "photos"
            jsonString = item.Value.ToString
    End Select
Next

ser = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
data = ser.Children().ToList
For Each item As JProperty In data
    item.CreateReader()
    Select Case item.Name
        Case "data"
            For Each comment As JObject In item.Values
                Dim _id As String = comment("id")
                Dim _title As String = comment("title")
                Dim _name As String = comment("name")
                Dim _source As String = comment("source")
                Dim source As List(Of JToken) = item.Value.ToList
                For Each images As JProperty In source
                    item.CreateReader()
                    Select Case item.Name
                        Case "images"
                            Dim _tempsource As String = source("source")
                            _source += _tempsource & vbCrLf
                    End Select
                Next
                Dim _created_time As String = comment("created_time")

                Dim itm As New ListViewItem(_id, 1)
                itm.SubItems.Add(_title)
                itm.SubItems.Add(_name)
                itm.SubItems.Add(_source)
                itm.SubItems.Add(_created_time)

                lvItems.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {itm})
                index += 1
            Next
    End Select
Next
```

I access this namespace with

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json 
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is not valid JSON, if it were, why not deserialize it?  I am not sure what the question is

Comment: @Plutonix 'photos' from the value is not parsed. program Throw 'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.' This Error

Comment: Improved formatting; added error message to the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to debug your JSON, because it is not valid. you must check whether your source is sending you invalid JSON, or there was a typo when posting it here. This would be valid JSON:

```
[{
    "data": [{
        "photos": {
            "data": [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "test Post",
                "images": [{
                    "height": 1024,
                    "source": "https://127.0.0.1:8080/image1.png",
                    "width": 1204
                }, {
                    "height": 1204,
                    "source": "https://127.0.0.1:8080/image2.png",
                    "width": 1204
                }]
            }]
        }
    }]
}]
```

Then, You can use a tool like [JSON Utils](http://jsonutils.com/) or VS itself (copying JSON to the clipboard and using **Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes**) to generate VB classes that match JSON structure:

```
Public Class Image
    Public Property height As Integer
    Public Property source As String
    Public Property width As Integer
End Class

Public Class PhotoDatum
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property images As Image()
End Class

Public Class Photos
    Public Property data As PhotoDatum()
End Class

Public Class Datum
    Public Property photos As Photos
End Class

Public Class SER
    Public Property data As Datum()
End Class
```

Anyway, if you add the classes above to your project, you can just do this:

```
Dim MySER = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of SER)(jsonString)
Dim itm As ListViewItem
Dim MyItems As New List(Of ListViewItem)
For Each d In MySER
    If d.photos IsNot Nothing Then
        For each dd in d.photos.data
            If dd.images IsNot Nothing Then
                For each img In dd.images
                    itm = New ListViewItem(dd.id, 1)
                    itm.SubItems.Add(dd.name)
                    itm.SubItems.Add(img.source)
                    MyItems.Add(itm)
                Next
            End If 
        Next
    End If
Next
lvItems.Items.AddRange(MyItems)
```

And work with your structured objects.

Comment: nice, but i want working in 'foreach' What should I do?

Comment: @LemonKnife, I edited my post and added a quick scrap of code after the conversion statement. Take a look and try to adapt it to your needs... I saw in your code that there is more metadata you'd like to collect and insert in your ListView, but the JSON you pasted contains just `id`, `name` and `source`. If your JSON gives more data, you'll need to add the corresponding fields to your classes. Good Luck!